# Removing index file from template group?

Tags: templates, 404

I am having an issue where if users try to access a page that doesn't exist within a template group, it displays a blank page instead of the 404. I believe this is due to the fact that the template groups have an index file in them that has no code. I would like to have a 404 page appear any time someone accesses a URL that doesn't exist within my site but I believe I have to remove the index files from my template groups for this to happen.

Does anyone know how I can accomplish this or a different solution to getting my 404 page to display instead of the blank white page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't delete index templates, so you'll have to include `{redirect='404'}` on those templates to force them to 404.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the EE docs on [404 pages](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/404pages.html), to get a understanding on how they work and how to set it up. Also I would remove the index files, that is just personal preference for me. You can do this by going into the Template Manager(Design -> Templates -> Template Manager). And delete each index file you don't want.

Comment: Thanks for the response, that's what I thought I should do but there is no delete option next to the index files in any of the template groups.

I have the 404 page configured correctly because it works on nonexistent URLs from the root of my site like: http://mysite.com/abcd but they don't work on any pages that are within a template group such as http://mysite.com/about/abcd

Comment: Sorry forgot about that, I am able to do it because I use Mountee and a Text Editor which it allows me to delete Index files. You can setup some code within the index to either forward them to another page, or integrate some logic with a 404 to stop them from going to those pages.